# Find parent PID of the webdriver.Remote instance

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to find the process id of the running webdriver instance from a python script. This script is often reloading and the original webdriver instance gets lost. When the script runs second time it tries to reconnect to the existing webdriver session using:

```
def attach_to_session(cls, executor_url, session_id):
        original_execute = webdriver.Remote.execute

        def new_command_execute(self, command, params=None):
            if command == "newSession":
                return {'success': 0, 'value': None, 'sessionId': session_id}
            return original_execute(self, command, params)

        webdriver.Remote.execute = new_command_execute
        driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=executor_url)
        webdriver.Remote.execute = original_execute
        return driver
```

The reconnection to existing webdriver sessions goes well. But when using **webdriver.Remote** I cannot use the below:

```
parent_process_id = psutil.Process(driver.service.process.pid).parent().pid
```

***AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'service'***

The solution using database to store the parent pid is not working for me because the records will not be refreshed.

The only solution i need is to use the webdriver.Remote instance of reconnected webdriver to find the parent in real time, if that is even possible.

Comment: why do you need parent process id or remote instance?